# Division with a 0. value and force digits in result

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I'm in need off assistance with some ZeroDivision.

In my example I got an optionMenu, that returns a value to a label, whitch is divided with an entry, then the result is shown in a new label in column 3.

I allways want to type an entry, that starts with an zero, like 0.250 etc. then this float is divided with the labels value from the optionMenu and then the result should be shown in a new label with digits.
It works fine with int, but thats not how it should work :) and now I'm a bit lost.

My following code looks like this and I would really appreciate a bit off help :) Thx in advance.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.materialPrice = {'Brick': 70, 'Rockwool': 50, 'Concrete': 20}

        materialvariable1 = StringVar(self, root)
        materialvariable1.set("Choose material")
        materialvariable2 = StringVar(self, root)
        materialvariable2.set("Choose materiale")

        self.w1 = OptionMenu(root, materialvariable1, *self.materialPrice, command=self.displayPrice)
        self.w1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

        self.w2 = OptionMenu(root, materialvariable2, *self.materialPrice, command=self.displayPrice2)
        self.w2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

        self.var = IntVar()
        self.var.set(float(0.00))
        self.var2 = IntVar()
        self.var2.set(float(0.00))

        self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.priceVarLabel1 = IntVar()
        self.priceVarLabel1.set(float(0.00))
        self.priceVarLabel2 = IntVar()
        self.priceVarLabel2.set(float(0.00))

        self.priceVarValue1 = Label(root, textvariable=self.priceVarLabel1, relief='sunken')
        self.priceVarValue1.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
        self.priceVarValue2 = Label(root, textvariable=self.priceVarLabel2, relief='sunken')
        self.priceVarValue2.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

        self.resultlabel1 = IntVar()
        self.resultlabel1.set(float(0.00))
        self.resultlabel2 = IntVar()
        self.resultlabel2.set(float(0.00))

        self.label1 = Label(root, textvariable=self.resultlabel1)
        self.label1.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
        self.label2 = Label(root, textvariable=self.resultlabel2)
        self.label2.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')


    def displayPrice(self, value):
        self.resultlabel1.set(self.var.get() / self.materialPrice[value])
        self.priceVarLabel1.set(self.materialPrice[value])

    def displayPrice2(self, value):
        self.resultlabel2.set(self.var2.get() / self.materialPrice[value])
        self.priceVarLabel2.set(self.materialPrice[value])



root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.title("help")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to use float values, use `DoubleVar`, `IntVar` is for integers.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the IntVar to DoubleVar did the trick and works great for me.. Now I have to figure out, how to change the digits length..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I change it to a DoubleVar, like my example.

But is there any way, that I can manage the digit length on the result?

```
    self.priceVarLabel1 = DoubleVar()
    self.priceVarLabel1.set(float(0.00))
```

Comment: what do mean mean by digit length

Comment: By digit length, I mean, to set the result in the labels, so it allways returns a float like 0.134 so its locked some how and is not returnning a float like 0.12359498464555

Comment: I want 1.200 decimal if it's possible

Comment: @AD WAN I think I found a way for controlling the decimals. I import decimal: Then self.var = DoubleVar()
        self.var.set(Decimal("0.100"))